# Adding directory to PATH, various ways and differences

Tags: environment-variables, paths

I have seen the thread
[How to add a directory to the PATH?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path)

I already have added the directory in my PATH by directly editing the `/etc/environment`. However, I do not get the command working when I use it as

`$ sudo command --options`

However, things work great when I do

`# command   --options`

or

`$ command --options`

Why is this the case? Also, this is not my full question. I would be thankful if someone could explain the various ways of adding directories to the path, how they work, and when is each of them in effect. How are they different?

The point of the question is not so much to get things working, but to understand how it all works. Pointing to a guide that explains this would be a great answer too.

Comment: Have you executed the _environment_ file using `source`?

Comment: No. What does that mean exactly, and what is it supposed to do?

Comment: If you modify a file that contains such environment variables and you want that change to kick in, you have to execute the modified file like so, `source FILE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add it to /root/.bashrc, /etc/profile, and /etc/bash.bashrc. It should work :)

The reason is that sudo uses the /root files, and not the system-wide files (or at least, in my experience).

Comment: how do you do this in ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @John it doesn't work?

Comment: no, i add the path to the directory the script is in to each file, and try to run it with sudo all i get is sudo: hello: command not found. i use the explicit path to the file.

Comment: @John don't use the explicit path to the file, use the parent folder. I.e. instead of specifying "/home/john/bin/hello", use "/home/john/bin/"

Comment: when i said file i should have said directory the file is in, or parent forlder. but that is what i do example: export PATH=${PATH}:/home/john/bin/

Comment: i even added it to /root/.profile

Comment: oh okay, hmm... so it works if you don't run it with `sudo`?